# Auto off bluetooth when the apps off

Tags: android

i want to write a function when the apps is close the Bluetooth can auto off. is there had any program code can use? Where i should put the code into my program? On create? On start?

Comment: You can disable the bluetooth adapter but you can't keep it from coming on unless you have a rooted device, AFAIK. Why would you want to do this, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

if you have your code ready to turn off your bluetooth . Put that code in ur onPause() method. whenever your activity is closed it also stop bluetooth adapter.

```
    public void onPause()
    {
       super.onPause();
       finish(); //this will close your app :)
       //Your code to turn of bluetooth
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to consider if the person who is using the apps will use it silent mode. or let's just say that we will be having a time alloted before we off the device / apps :) it is just a simple suggestion before we go further on that one :)

Comment: I'm not sure what this "answer" even really means but I think it should be a comment

Comment: in my apps is no silent mode. just turn on the apps and turn off the apps

Comment: in there had any example code the people use to auto disable Bluetooth?